# php Regular expression adding link to href

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

hi i'm very new at programing.
I dont know how to write a php regulat expression to add something between href=" and some text after it
how to make this

```
<a class="aaa" href="/some/file.html">
```

to look like

```
<a class="aaa" href="http://www.example.com/some/file.html">
```

it is necessary to match links with "aaa" class.

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 2):

[You better don't even start trying to do this with regular expressions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

You should use a DOM parser for tasks like this. [This one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) for example makes your life really easy.

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($input);

foreach($html->find('a[class=aaa]') as $link)
    $link->href = "http://www.example.com".$link->href;

$result = $html->save();
```

`find` lets you query the DOM very nicely. The parameter is `tagtype[attributeName=attributeValue]` where the square brackets are an optional filter. Then you just iterate over every link this function finds, and prepend the `href` attribute with your domain.

If you cannot use 3rd-party libraries for some reason, PHP comes with a built-in [DOM module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). The code will not be quite as short and elegant, but it is still highly preferable to trying to come up with a robust regex.

Comment: I really prisiate your help, and i know it will work if i know how to use it but i can't put my code together with your code can you pls do a quick preview on the post below, I posted my code as a ANSWER.
Thank you very mutch m.buettner

Comment: ps. I dont know how to include that Simple HTML DOM on my file

Comment: This is a great example.  I've added it to http://htmlparsing.com/php.html so future HTML parsers can see it.

Comment: @user1898399 you download the php file from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/), put it into your project and call `include "simple_html_dom.php";` somewhere. then you rename the variable in your code below to `$input` and copy my code after that. by the way, you can find the `example`-div using `simple_html_dom`, too. no need for regex at all

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
$string = '<a class="aaa" href="/some/file.html">';
$pattern = '~class="aaa" href="(.*)"~isU'; 
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);

$string = str_replace($matches[1],"http://www.example.com".$matches[1],$string);

echo $string;
```

Edited to match class="aaa" but I'd also recommend m.buettners way if you're doing things like that a lot.

Comment: that again, will apply the regex to all links (not only the ones with class `aaa`). plus, there is no need to match and capture anything after `href="`

Comment: You're absolutely right, I kinda read over the "it is necessary to match links with "aaa" class." - my fault. I also agree with you about the simple html dom, I use it a lot. I just thought this task is simple so he could use regex.

Comment: thank you for you replay but I'm geting this message:
Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in